# Unable to get managed connection

Tags: jakarta-ee, wildfly, resource-adapter

I am working on a resource adapter where I periodically get the following exception

```
23:17:22,280 WARNING [com.xelapos.xpark.core.ejb.HardwareAction] (default task-1) IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:/eis/xPark/Barrier: jakarta.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:/eis/xPark/Barrier
        at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@3.0.4.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:690)
        at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@3.0.4.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:597)
        at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@3.0.4.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:789)
        at xpark.barrier//com.xelapos.xpark.barrier.adapter.out.BarrierConnectionFactoryImpl.getConnection(BarrierConnectionFactoryImpl.java:28)
        at deployment.core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war//com.xelapos.xpark.core.ejb.HardwareAction.openBarrier(HardwareAction.java:135)
        at deployment.core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war//com.xelapos.xpark.core.ejb.HardwareAction.openBarrier(HardwareAction.java:129)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
        at org.jboss.as.ee@30.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:35)
        at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:509)
        at org.jboss.as.weld.common@30.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.delegateInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:62)
        at org.jboss.as.weld.common@30.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:72)
        at org.jboss.as.weld.common@30.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:85)
        at org.jboss.as.ee@30.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:46)
        at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3@30.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:26)
        at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.jpa@30.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:30)
        at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3@30.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.EjbBMTInterceptor.handleInvocation(EjbBMTInterceptor.java:86)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3@30.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.BMTInterceptor.processInvocation(BMTInterceptor.java:40)
        at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ee@30.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:28)
        at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:40)
        at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:53)
        at org.jboss.as.ee@30.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:35)
        at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3@30.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:34)
        at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3@30.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:39)
        at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:509)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.2.Final//org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:78)
        at org.jboss.as.weld.common@30.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:72)
        at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3@30.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:24)
        at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3@30.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:30)
        at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3@30.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.IdentityOutflowInterceptor.processInvocation(IdentityOutflowInterceptor.java:56)
        at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3@30.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityDomainInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityDomainInterceptor.java:27)
        at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3@30.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.StartupAwaitInterceptor.processInvocation(StartupAwaitInterceptor.java:27)
        at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3@30.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:47)
        at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3@30.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:50)
        at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ee@30.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:33)
        at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:60)
        at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:438)
        at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@2.2.2.Final//org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:633)
        at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:57)
        at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:53)
        at org.jboss.as.ee@30.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:181)
        at org.jboss.as.ee@30.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:174)
        at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3@30.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.IdentityInterceptor.lambda$processInvocation$0(IdentityInterceptor.java:30)
        at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@2.2.2.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.SecurityIdentity.runAsFunctionEx(SecurityIdentity.java:421)
        at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@2.2.2.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.Scoped.runAsFunctionEx(Scoped.java:161)
        at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@2.2.2.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.Scoped.runAsSupplierEx(Scoped.java:229)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3@30.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.IdentityInterceptor.processInvocation(IdentityInterceptor.java:30)
        at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:53)
        at org.jboss.as.ee@30.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:64)
        at deployment.core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war//com.xelapos.xpark.core.ejb.HardwareAction$$$view2.openBarrier(Unknown Source)
        at deployment.core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war//com.xelapos.xpark.core.service.AccessControlServiceImpl.lambda$exit$9(AccessControlServiceImpl.java:210)
        at deployment.core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war//com.xelapos.xpark.core.service.AbstractService.execute(AbstractService.java:35)
        at deployment.core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war//com.xelapos.xpark.core.service.AccessControlServiceImpl.exit(AccessControlServiceImpl.java:199)
        at deployment.core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war//com.xelapos.xpark.core.api.AccessControlEndpoint.exit(AccessControlEndpoint.java:113)
        at deployment.core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war//com.xelapos.xpark.core.api.AccessControlEndpoint$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.exit(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@6.2.5.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:154)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@6.2.5.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:118)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@6.2.5.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:560)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@6.2.5.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTargetAfterFilter(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:452)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@6.2.5.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invokeOnTarget$2(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:413)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@6.2.5.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:321)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@6.2.5.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:415)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@6.2.5.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:378)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@6.2.5.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:356)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@6.2.5.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:70)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@6.2.5.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:429)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@6.2.5.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:240)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@6.2.5.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:154)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@6.2.5.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:321)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@6.2.5.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:157)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@6.2.5.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:229)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@6.2.5.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:222)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@6.2.5.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@6.2.5.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
        at jakarta.servlet.api@6.0.0//jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:614)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
        at org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server@4.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.ElytronRunAsHandler.lambda$handleRequest$1(ElytronRunAsHandler.java:68)
        at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@2.2.2.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.FlexibleIdentityAssociation.runAsFunctionEx(FlexibleIdentityAssociation.java:103)
        at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@2.2.2.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.Scoped.runAsFunctionEx(Scoped.java:161)
        at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@2.2.2.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.Scoped.runAs(Scoped.java:73)
        at org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server@4.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.ElytronRunAsHandler.handleRequest(ElytronRunAsHandler.java:67)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:117)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
        at io.undertow.core@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.DisableCacheHandler.handleRequest(DisableCacheHandler.java:33)
        at io.undertow.core@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.core@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:53)
        at io.undertow.core@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:60)
        at io.undertow.core@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server-servlet@4.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.servlet.CleanUpHandler.handleRequest(CleanUpHandler.java:38)
        at io.undertow.core@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@30.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:44)
        at io.undertow.core@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@30.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:51)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SendErrorPageHandler.handleRequest(SendErrorPageHandler.java:52)
        at io.undertow.core@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:276)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:132)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@30.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1413)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@30.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1413)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@30.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1413)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@30.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1413)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:256)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:101)
        at io.undertow.core@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:393)
        at io.undertow.core@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:859)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
        at org.jboss.xnio@3.8.11.Final//org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1282)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
Caused by: jakarta.resource.ResourceException: IJ000655: No managed connections available within configured blocking timeout (30000 [ms])
        at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@3.0.4.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.java:579)
        at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@3.0.4.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getSimpleConnection(AbstractPool.java:688)
        at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@3.0.4.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getConnection(AbstractPool.java:653)
        at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@3.0.4.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:624)
        ... 144 more
```

I'm giving the full message because I really have no idea where to look for the problem (and what part of the adapter code to show). Please help to locate the problem (tell me what to add in the question).

Apparently I'm not closing the connection correctly because the connection pool is overflowing (I can perform exactly 20 operations).